# csrf валидация в yii2. Ошибка: "Не удалось проверить данные"

Tags: yii2, csrf

На проекте при отправке формы периодически возникает ошибка csrf валидации

```
yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Не удалось проверить переданные данные. in /var/www/moeirc/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:166
```

Форма достаточно простая, содержит в себе всего несколько полей, никакой сложной логики или отправки файлов.  Отправляется с помощью `ajax`.
Ошибка возникает достаточно редко, и я никак не могу выявить причину.
На данный момент известно, что ошибка происхоидит независимо от данных отправленных в форме, ситуация когда пользователь открыл страницу в нескольких окнах, и спустя некоторое время пытается отправить форму тоже исключается, ситуация когда форма загружена, а отправка происходит через какое то продолжительное время - так же исключена. Максимальное зафиксированое время между загрузкой и отправкой формы ~2000 секунд, хотя ошибка бывает и при ~150-200 секундах. На локальном сервере воспроизвести ошибку не получается

Пока что на ум приходит только следующее:
Проект загружен на 2ух фронт-энд серверах(nginx) и 4х бэкэндах. Может ли происходить такая ситуация, когда форма загружается с одного бэкэнда, а отправляется на другой бэкэнд? Я не совсем разобрался как генерурется csrf параметр на сервере, но возможен ли из-за этого конфликт? Хотя, судя по настройкам csrf параметр хранится в куках у клиента, а не в сессии сервера. Если ошибка происходит именно из-за этого, то какие могут быть пути решения проблемы?

Проект собран на basic шаблоне, вот настройка компонента request.

```
'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => '_OgryIAX7GtLaeqeVFNyZJNIrqmeVzmR',
            'csrfParam' => 'project/name',
        ],
```

Так же, хочу добавить что форма генерурется с помощью `ActiveForm` и csrf парметры всегда прописываются в вёрстке. `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>` так же присутствует в лейауте

Comment: А такая ошибка только на ajax возникает или при обычной отправке тоже? Возможно при отправке ajax, некорректно или с ошибкой собираются данные из формы. Либо доп.валидация какая или еще чего вызывает ошибку. Надо дополнительно убедиться, что данные csrf всегда отправляются на сервер вместе с формой.

Comment: @fedornabilkin Да, данная ошибка возникает только на `ajax`. Какие то другие валидации ошибки не вызывают, потому как  ошибка `Не удалось проверить переданные данные.` говорит именно о проблемах с `csrf-валидацией`.
Сейчас все сессии пишутся в один redis, независимо от того на каком бэкэнд-сервере выполняется скрипт - это не помогло решить проблему. Сейчас добавил в ajax-запрос вручную заголовок `X-CSRF-Token` (хотя фреймворк должен это делать сам), нужно посмотреть какое то время, будут ли ошибки или нет.

Comment: А в консоле в браузере есть ошибки js, когда отправляешь форму?

Comment: @fedornabilkin за консоль ничего не могу сказать, т.к. не могу воспроизвести ошибку локально. Мне приходят только отчеты об ошибках